# Unable to save data frame as Hive table, throwing file not found exception

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When I am trying to save data frame as Hive table in pyspark

```
df_writer.saveAsTable('hive_table', format='parquet', mode='overwrite')
```

I am getting following error:

> Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path
>   does not exist:
>   hdfs://hostname:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/testdb.db/hive_table     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:287)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)

I have the path till 'hdfs://hostname:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/testdb.db/'

Please provide your inputs

Answer (score 0):

Try using DataFrameWriter as

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).insertInto(s"${dbName}.${t.table}")
```